# sage install set up on debian server, help setting up correct DOT_SAGE permissions

Tags: php, google-app-engine, permissions, debian, sage

i just installed sage 6.2 from source on a debian server, then..

1)  command  `sage -c 'print (3+5)'`

1. **WORKS** as expected from terminal
2. **FAILS** from php script `exec("sage -c 'print (3+5)'", $output[]);`

   throws the error 
   `Error: environment variable $HOME is not set.
   Error setting environment variables by sourcing '/mysoft/sage-6.2/src/bin/sage-env';...`

2) partial fix:
   set `export HOME='/var/www/junk'`  in sage-env file

3) now

1. LINE command `sage -c 'print (3+5)'` **FAILS**  from terminal log shows.. `"...OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/junk/.sage/db'..."`
2. PHP script  `exec("sage -c 'print (3+5)'", $output[]);` **WORKS** as expected

so it seems i can make sage work thru command line or thru php script but not both at same time. depending on if i comment out 
`export HOME='/var/www/junk'` or not..

moreover the real trouble is that with `export HOME='/var/www/junk'`  the entire server does not copy  or back up correctly throwing errors about permissions on the .sage directory.. and making all server backups  useless  [specifically using google cloud computing snapshots to back up entire server, but also throws errors even when taring the www directory ]...

ultimately i want to be able to able to run the php exec version of sage AND be able to back up and copy snapshots of server with no errors..   all help is MUCH appreciated as this is driving me crazy....